# How can i make a word document generator on python?

Tags: python

So I've only known how to code for three months. So don't judge me. So I'm trying to create a program that generates word documents for me on Python 3.6. I want the program to ask a couple of questions that you can answer in a pop window, and with that information, it can generate a word document. I would appreciate any help, also teach me the words.

Comment: https://python-docx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Answer (score 0):

A good first step would be to learn how to write to files.

By "word document" I'm assuming you're referring to a .doc file?  As in a Microsoft Word document?

If so, there are libraries that can help you.

https://python-docx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/